# How to match just whole words and ignore special characthers

Tags: regex

For this example let's say we have following keywords:

```
banana
apple.
apple-
apple  party #(double space)    
apple pie
sweet apple pie
apple
apple 34
```

How to make regex match only "apple" words without special characters and more then one space? So from example above it would only match last 4 and ignore first 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\bapple\b(?!\s{2}|\S)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xF9zR1/1)

This works by requiring a word boundary (`\b`) before and after the word and excluding matches followed by two spaces or a non-whitespace character.

---

**Edit:** You indicated in your comment that you want to match the entire line. This is easy; just add `.*` before and after the regex above, like this:

```
.*?\bapple\b(?!\s{2}|\S).*
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xF9zR1/3) (I added a `?` to the first `.*` to avoid performance problems due to backtracking.)

---

**Edit 2:** Based on additional comments: you also want to exclude matches like `apple . com`. This is a little trickier, but this regex will do it:

```
(?!.*?\bapple\b(?:\s{2}|\s*[.\/,<>-])).*?\bapple\b.*
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xF9zR1/4). This one works by using a negative lookahead. The group `(?!.*?\bapple\b(?:\s{2}|\s*[.\/,<>-]))` means that the line must *not* contain `apple` with either (a) 2+ spaces or (b) any number of spaces and a character in the set `./,<>-` after it. This should do what you want.

Comment: THANKS! This looks correct, only one issue: Is it possible that it maches whole sentence or line containg the word? 

In the example "sweet apple pie" only apple is matched.

Comment: @NemaGa Sure; see my edit. Adding `.*` before and after the regex will cause it to match the whole line. It's actually best to do `.*?` before and `.*` after for performance reasons.

Comment: One small issue though(sorry poorly explained it), code still matches for example "apple . com" is it possible to make it completely ignore these special characters (.-/,<>)

Comment: @NemaGa Can you clarify a bit? Should it exclude any instances of `apple` that have a special character before the next word?

Comment: Exactly, if special character is present anywhere in sentence/line it shouldn't match.

Comment: @NemaGa I edited the answer again. This ought to do it. If you need additional tweaks, you may want to ask a new question and reference this one for context.